# how to get related product by product keyword(meta keyword) in magento?

Tags: magento, phpmyadmin, magento-1.7

I've to get related products according to the **keyword** of the product in magento.

Is there is any way to do that.

Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Use this extension](http://www.magentocommerce.com/magento-connect/advanced-related-products-9204.html)
I've use this extension,its works well.I fix the issue.